# need help changing width or height of an html 5 video with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video

I need help changing the height or width of this html 5 video. I am using html 5 and javascript to try to change the size of the video.

The following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("mainvideo").setAttribute(height,'400px');
alert('Hello');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<video id="mainvideo">
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
This is Fall Back Content
</video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a css file that does not do anything but align the video to the middle of the screen. Is this a java script problem that is not changing the height of this video to 400px? or an html 5 problem. I also dont have a local video on me to display on screen if that is the problem also. Thanks to anyone that can help out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
       document.getElementById("mainvideo").style.height='400px';
       alert('Hello');
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<video id="mainvideo">
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
This is Fall Back Content
</video>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think `height` is an attribute anymore, it's a CSS property.

edit: Actually, It may never have been an HTML attribute. According to http://www.codehelp.co.uk/html/deprecated.html, `width` used to be an attribute, but not height.

Comment: Alright thank you. That is good to know. It still does not seem to display. Could that be because I dont have a video to show?

Comment: @tdelaney18, No, it's because at the time that code is run, your element doesn't exist yet. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok I am sorry to bug you but if I change this code to what you have then the video shows for a split second and then disappears. Am I missing something?

Comment: @tdelaney18, Are you testing offline or online? If you're testing online, it would be easier for me to help you if I could see the page in question. I have yet to dive into HTML5, though, so I'm not sure about most of it.

Comment: Offline today. If this is too much that is fine. I am just gonna try to figure this out tonight. Thank you for the help though

Comment: @tdelaney18, No problem. I wish I could help more. Are you sure it's nothing wrong with the video itself? You should try linking to an online video that you know works.

Comment: Yes! it works with a YouTube video. So that works for me. Thank you

Comment: Some how it doesn't work via WPF WebBrowser control. I put my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630528/cannot-change-video-tag-size-via-invokescript-of-wpf-webbrowser-control